# Custom styled FBML widget

Tags: css, facebook, fbml

Is possible to change style of facebook web widgets? I really would like to create own like-box, but I cant..I can simply change style from webkit inspector, but in case I try it from internal CSS or even with javascript, it doesn't work..Please help..Thanks